# Installing Tenda W311mi USB adabter on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, ubuntu-22.04

*I want to install Tenda USB wifi adabter on my ubuntu by making the Makefile according to this site guidness:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Tenda_W311M
and download all of the links from these sites:
https://www.tendacn.com/fr/download/detail-4785.html
https://www.tendacn.com/fr/download/detail-2646.html
and this is my dongle of Tenda USB:
[image]

I used

```
$ sudo make
```

and this is my result

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ali/MT7601U_LinuxAP_3.0.0.1_20130802/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ali/MT7601U_LinuxAP_3.0.0.1_20130802/tools'
/home/ali/MT7601U_LinuxAP_3.0.0.1_20130802/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/ali/MT7601U_LinuxAP_3.0.0.1_20130802/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-43-generic/build 
SUBDIRS=/home/ali/MT7601U_LinuxAP_3.0.0.1_20130802/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-43-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed 
by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-43-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:388: LINUX] Error 2
```

How can i setup Tenda USB Wifi on my ubuntu

please HELP ME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how can we solve the ubuntu wifi adapter

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/McMCCRU/rtl8188gu.git
cd rtl8188gu
make
sudo make install
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware 
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this step to enable WiFi  in Ubuntu22.04
go to show applications option and search for Additional drivers

[image]

under Ubuntu  Software --> Download from --> Main Server
[image]

Go to Additional Drivers tab --> Choose using BroadCom 802... option

[image]

apply changes
oncne changes are completed you can see Wifi Drivers are enabled and connecte to WiFi